# The use of arrays within structures

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

I'm currently studying C++ on a book I bought a month ago. So now here I am, studying the new chapter that talks about structures. 
The book gives a problem: Write a program that allows a user to enter high scores of a game, keeping tracking of the name
of the user and the score. Add the ability to show the highest score for each user, all scores for a
particular user, all scores from all users, and the list of users.

My problem is... how to store a lot of scores of the same player, using a structure. 
I thought something like this:

```
struct my_string
{
    string name;
    int score[100];
    int lvp;
};
```

Declaring an array, within a structure, it's something that can be done? I'm not entirely sure. 
After that, in the main function, I declared an array of my_string type.

Like this:

```
my_string name_score[100];
```

I was thinking about using 2 counters, one that is related to the name, and the other related to the scores. Something like this:

```
name_score[0].score[2];
```

So, this piece of code should give me back the third score, of the first name (player). 
Am I saying nonsense, or this can be done?

Comment: Arrays can be used normally in C++ wherever any kind of variable can be declared, be it locally in a function, globally, in a class or a struct.

Comment: I think that can be done, and does make sense.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Is a function parameter considered a declaration?  I"m not sure if it is, but I think it should be clarified that arrays can in fact *not* be used normally wherever any other kind of variable can be used.  In particular, as function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you are exactly right! That should work perfectly.

Basically your first closed brackets will give you the player and the .score[] will give you their entry.

Answer (score 0):

So this code is valid code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct my_string
{
    std::string name;
    int score[100];
    int lvp;
};

int main()
{
    my_string name_score[100];

    //Initializing of data in name_score assumed here

    std::cout << name_score[0].score[2] << std::endl ;
}
```

Since this is C++ you may want to consider using `std::vector<int> score` as opposed to `int score[100]` or even `std::array` if you are using C++11 they are both superior to old C style array. The same thing goes for `my_string` although you might want to pick a more descriptive name.